# Script tag injection with synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, eval

I have to add a script tag via some JavaScript *and* have it execute in full as the later statements rely on it.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Injecting Script Tags</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Injecting Script Tags</h1>

        <script>
            console.log('starting');
            var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            newScriptTag.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js';
            newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
            document.head.appendChild(newScriptTag);
            try {
                var now = moment().format('HH:mm');
                console.log(`moment loaded.  The time is ${now}`);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Moment not loaded: ${e}`);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As the snippet above shows, the `moment()` isn't available on the statement after the tag insertion.

I *think* it could be done with `eval(...)`, but that option isn't popular.

Answer (score -1):

use onload event

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Injecting Script Tags</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Injecting Script Tags</h1>

        <script>
            console.log('starting');
            var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            newScriptTag.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js';
            newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScriptTag.onload = function(){
                try {
                    var now = moment().format('HH:mm');
                    console.log(`moment loaded.  The time is ${now}`);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(`Moment not loaded: ${e}`);
                }

            };
            document.head.appendChild(newScriptTag);
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```